How to call `org-sparse-tree` with tags from lisp?
I am normally pressing some keyboard shortcuts to open a sparse-tree in org-mode. I'd like to open sparse-trees from Lisp, by calling org-sparse-tree from Lisp. However, when you call it from Lisp it still opens a selection window where the user can select the search query. How can we call this function and provide the sparse-tree search-query within Lisp itself, by passing a tag?
Edit: Here is a similar question but the answer only works for "todo" sparse trees.

This is a link-only question, so it should be deleted. Pose whatever is relevant to a question in the question itself.

@Drew, fixed, sorry.

Thx............

org-sparse-tree is just a dispatcher: it asks for input to be typed by the user and based on that input, it dispatches to one of several functions. Read its code to find out what functions it calls in each case (C-h f org-sparse-tree and click on the link at the end of first line). If you want to do the equivalent from Lisp, you will have to call the function for the type you want - or write your own dispatcher which takes the type as an argument, rather than asking the user to type it.
